# What is "crossover probability" in optimization techniques?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, optimization

I am new to optimization methods. What is the meaning of "crossover probability" in optimization methods? I was reading the following lines from an article that this question came into my mind:

> In unmodified differential
> evolution (DE) algorithm, ***crossover probability*** is constant and remains unchanged during the whole optimization process,
> resulting in the negative effect on the population diversity and convergence speed.

Comment: We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking.  This helps us ensure that questions are of high quality and useful to others, and that our site is contributing useful new knowledge.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.

Comment: If your question is answered in standard resources, like textbooks or Wikipedia, you probably need to do more research before asking.  In this case, the question seems to be answered by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm), which is an indication that more research would be appropriate.

Comment: @D.W. I disagree. Yes, "crossover" makes sense in the context of genetic algorithms, but in the absence of more context it's not at all obvious what "crossover probability" might mean. The Wikipedia page you link contains only one occurrence of the word "probability" and it's not part of the expression "crossover probability".

Comment: @Stef, OK!  In that case I think an appropriate approach would be to describe in the question what research the poster has done and what resources they've read, what their current understanding is, and what specifically they are unsure about.   The first Wikipedia article does use the phrase "crossover probability", though it doesn't define it.  A websearch for "crossover probability" immediately turns up definitions of that phrase.

Comment: Please provide a full citation for the original source you are quoting from.  See our guidelines: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  I recommend including the title of the paper, the authors, where it was published, and a link to a freely available PDF (if one is available).

Comment: @Stef: are you aware of other randomized optimization techniques that use genetic terminology ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust For some value of "aware", yes.

Comment: @Stef: feel free to share.